# Why is my recursive memoized Fibonacci code wrong?

Tags: java

Something in the main function is wrong, but I don't know what. If I go through the code with a debugger I can see that my code isn't even reaching the fibonacci function right now.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n=1; n<50; n++) {
            System.out.println("Element "+ n + " of the sequence: " + newFib(n));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<BigInteger> memo = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    static BigInteger newFib(int n){
        assert n >= 1: "the fibonacci sequence starts at 1"; 
        BigInteger result=BigInteger.valueOf(1);

        if (memo.get(n) != null) {
            return memo.get(n);
        }
        else if( n  == 1  || n  ==  2 ) {
            memo.add(n, BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        }
        else {
            result= newFib(n-1).add(newFib(n-2));
            memo.add(n,result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You code goes into `newFib()` just fine for me.  Of course, it then blows up when you try to access a non-existing entry in `memo`, but that's a different problem...

Comment: *`assert n >= 1: "the fibonacci sequence starts at 1";`* Not [necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Negafibonacci).

Comment: Test the size of the array instead of trying to access an element that might not be defined. Your code is currently throwing an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Could someone explain what's wrong, since the problem isn't in the main function? Why does it blow up when I'm trying to enter a non existing entry in memo? Because shouldn't it just skip the if statement if im trying to enter a non existing entry in memo?

Comment: Java doesn't implicitly handle program errors like that.  You should either perform a check to make sure you aren't about to do something that will throw an error, or surround the call in a try/catch block and handle the error gracefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was throwing some exceptions.  You simply needed to debug the exceptions and implement the proper checks.  Using the code with these changes should work as intended:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n=1; n<50; n++) {
        System.out.println("Element "+ n + " of the sequence: " + newFib(n));
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<BigInteger> memo = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        static BigInteger newFib(int n){
            assert n >= 1: "the fibonacci sequence starts at 1"; 
            BigInteger result=BigInteger.valueOf(1);

            if (memo.size() - 1 >= n && memo.get(n) != null) {
                return memo.get(n);
            }
            else if( n  == 1  || n  ==  2 ) {
                memo.add(n-1, BigInteger.valueOf(1));
                return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            }
            else {
                result= newFib(n-1).add(newFib(n-2));
                memo.add(n,result);
                return result;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the changes you made? Why did you add `memo.size() - 1 >= n` and why did you change `memo.add(n, BigInteger.valueOf(1));` to `memo.add(n-1, BigInteger.valueOf(1));`?

Comment: In your program, `n` is the used to indicate the `nth` fib number, NOT the index of the fib number.  So the 1st fib number is where n equals 1, but in an ArrayList, that would have to go into index 0.  That's why I changed it to check you are trying to calculate a number that you don't have stored yet (out of bounds) or not.

Comment: The memo.add change is just so that you are adding to the right index, which should be 1 less than the number of fib number you are on

Comment: Shouldn't it be `memo.add(n-1, result);`in the `else` part as well?

Comment: Nevermind, you access `return memo.get(n)` (needs to be `return memo.get(n-1);` as well, then), but I guess you have one open spot in the `ArrayList` in the end (index `0`).

Comment: I understand now what you mean by the difference between `n` and the index of the ArrayList, but I still can't understand `memo.size() - 1 >= n`. Could you explain what the program is doing with and with that line of code?

Comment: It's checking to make sure that if you are about to call memo.get(n), that index n needs to exist with a value.  `memo.size() - 1` will give you the last index with a value, so if `n` is bigger than that, then you know that it won't exist in the array and you should skip over that part.

Comment: Ah okay i understand, but what I still don't understand is why is `memo.get(n) != null` not enough to satisfy that condition you just mentioned? And related to @jgb comments; im now confused why we're using n and not n-1 in the other cases

Comment: @Andy Array indices start at zero, but your Fibonacci sequence starts at 1, so you have to shift indices. In the beginning, the `ArrayList` is empty, has a size of `0`, but you are trying to access `memo.get(1)` (because you start counting with `1`). Hence, you are trying to access an element beyond the extend of the `ArrayList`, whence you get the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. When starting with `1` you need to offset all you array indices by `-1`.

Comment: Exactly @gjb that's why I find it confusing why we aren't changing all variables `n` to `n-1`. So: in the `if` statement `memo.get(n) != null` becomes `memo.get(n-1) != null`  and `return memo.get(n)` becomes `return memo.get(n-1)`. And in the `else` statement `memo.add(n,result)` becomes `memo.add(n-1,result)`. (And I understand letting my Fibonacci sequence start at just 0 simplifies it already a lot, but I would still like to fully understand the mistake I made)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does not handle out of bounds correctly and as I mentioned in the comments, the fibonacci sequence does not necessarily start at one and the logic can be simplified. I would use a `HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>` for storing the memoization and I would also prefer to populate the initial constants once (and as constants). For example,

```
private static Map<Integer, BigInteger> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(0, BigInteger.ZERO);
    memo.put(1, BigInteger.ONE);
}

static BigInteger newFib(int n) {
    if (!memo.containsKey(n)) {
        if (n < 0) {
            memo.put(n, newFib(n + 2).subtract(newFib(n + 1)));
        } else {
            memo.put(n, newFib(n - 2).add(newFib(n - 1)));
        }
    }
    return memo.get(n);
}
```

Which can then be tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = -8; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i != -8) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.printf("%-5s", String.format("F(%d)", i));
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = -8; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i != -8) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.printf("%-5s", newFib(i));
    }
}
```

To reproduce the example given in the [Fibonacci number Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Negafibonacci).

```
F(-8) F(-7) F(-6) F(-5) F(-4) F(-3) F(-2) F(-1) F(0)  F(1)  F(2)  F(3)  F(4)  F(5)  F(6)  F(7)  F(8) 
-21   13    -8    5     -3    2     -1    1     0     1     1     2     3     5     8     13    21
```